# How to fix 500 Code Server Error Next JS API and OpenAI

Tags: next.js, openai-api

I am trying to build a chat bot with the OPEN AI GPT 3.5 turbo Model in NextJS. However when I send a POST request to http://localhost:3000/api/generate I get a Response with status code 500 and this error message:

[image]

src/page/api/generate.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { OpenAIApi, Configuration } from "openai";

type ResData = {};

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResData>
) {
  try {
    const prompt = req.body.prompt;

    const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: prompt }],
    });

    const result = completion.data.choices[0].message?.content;

    return res.status(200).json({ result });
  } catch (reason) {
    const message = reason instanceof Error ? reason.message : reason;
    console.log("API failure:", message);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}
```

src/pages/index.tsx

```
    try {
      console.log("Getting response from OpenAI...");

      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch("/api/generate", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ prompt: "Hello World" }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } 
   };
```

I'm new to NextJS, thank you for answering

---

### edited by 7.13

and I also use http-proxy-middleware in server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
  target: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
  changeOrigin: true,
  timeout: 60000, // 60秒超时时间
});

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.use('/api', apiProxy);

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
  });
});
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    OPENAI_API_KEY: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    PORT : process.env.PORT,
    API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
  },
  // async rewrites() {
  //   return [
  //     {
  //       source: '/api/:path*',
  //       destination: 'http://localhost:3001/api/:path*',
  //     },
  //   ]
  // }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: You would get more information on the error in the terminal window you have started the app from. Then, the file path in the question must be wrong. First, you have the code in `/app/...` but the second is in `/pages/...` I guess you could make it work but it is much cleaner to have the code inside of src or not but not both. Furthermore, assuming that the API is in the app router (as the path would suggest), the filename to match your URL would be `/app/api/generate/route.ts` and the signature is wrong for app router. I guess you might just need to move the `generate.ts` to `/src/pages/api`

Comment: sorry i wrote the wrong path, the path is correctly "src/pages/api/generates.ts", but it didn't work either

Comment: You still should get some info in the terminal where you started the app. Can you share this?

Comment: sure, this is info:
API failure: connect ECONNREFUSED 130.211.15.150:443
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...

Comment: Not sure why your app tries to connect to 130.211.15.150:443 but it can't and that is your problem. Do you have any firewall or proxy that would limit outbound trafic?

Comment: i have a proxy config in next.config.js

Comment: can you `console.log(prompt)` after `const prompt = req.body.prompt;` to see if it is a valid string type